# MsgPack serialization throw an error

Tags: c#, msgpack

I trying to create a serializer like this

```
var serializer = MsgPack.Serialization.MessagePackSerializer.Create<tickdata>();
```

It will serialize the class tickdata.

```
namespace TickDataDefinition
{
public class tickdata
{
    public List<data> _data=new List<data>();        
    public int returncount()
    {
        return _data.Count;
    }
}

public class data
{
    enum type { trade, quote }

    long time;
    double bid1;
    double ask1;
    double bidsize;
    double asksize;
    double price;
    uint size;

    public data(long t,double b,double a,double bs, double ask)
    {
        time = t;
        bid1 = b;
        ask1 = a;
        bidsize = bs;
        asksize = ask;     
    }
    public data(long t,double p,uint s)
    {
        time = t;
        price=p;
        size=s;
    }

}
```

}

Strangely this code does not work. The error is "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the exception, but try this:

In most serializations you should have parameterless constructors in your classes. Add below constructor,

```
public data()
{

}
```

As far as I know serialization classes use this constructor to create an instance.

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve the problem. I tried.